# Подскажите как правильно прописать массив?

Tags: php, mysql, json, веб-программирование, curl

Есть код, он работает отлично, но я не знаю как сделать так, что-бы в этот код
$result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id IN **(5,2,3,1,6)**'); автоматически подтягивались ID из этого адреса ? https://ads.pontogram.com/restid.php

Полный код

```
<?php


// указывается адрес, где находится (хостится) ваша база данных
$sdd_db_host='localhost';

// указывается имя базы данных, с которой скрипт будет работать.
// Это обязательно, так как баз может быть множество на одном сервере
$sdd_db_name='*******';

// логин доступа к базе данных
$sdd_db_user='********';

// пароль доступа к базе данных
$sdd_db_pass='********';

// установка связи с сервером (@ подавление возможных ошибок)
@mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);

// переключение на нужную базу данных
@mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);

$res = file_get_contents("https://ads.pontogram.com/restid.php");
// выполнение SQL запроса и получение всех записей (строк) из таблицы `table_name`
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id IN ($res)  ");




// получение результатов из каждой строки
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ // вывод данных
  echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$row['latitude'].','.$row['longitude'].'),';
}// /while
?>
```

ID получаю в другой таблице но в этой же базе, название базы orders ячейка restaurant_id, отсюда как раз эти id 1,2,2,2,2, и так далее.

Comment: Касательно вашего вопроса - так. Но так делать не стоит, это совсем не правильно

```$res = file_get_contents("https://ads.pontogram.com/restid.php"); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id IN ($res)");```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли!

Comment: И еще вопрос, а как сделать так, что например есть id 1,2,2,2,2 что бы запись из базы выводилась не один раз под id2 а все, сколько будет прописано в массиве ?

Comment: @Crasher Возможно ли это сделать ?

Comment: можно конечно, всё можно сделать, только моском покумекать.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Я уже сотни стр. прочитал где есть какие-то примеры, вроде вопросы те же есть, а ответов нет (( был бы я программистом то не писал бы тут :)

Comment: ну так вопросы надо задавать конкретнее, поподробнее.

Comment: @Jean-Claude С вопросом который я задал, мне помогли, в комментарии я задал дополнительный вопрос, как сделать так что бы выводились дубли результата 1,2,2,2,2 id1 и четыре дубля id2, ID всегда динамичные, это "1,2,2,2,2" пример, может быть и так https://ads.pontogram.com/restid.php если у вас знание как это можно сделать, был бы рад вашей помощи.

Comment: Думаю, Вам стоит приложить свой код, чтобы понять, что у Вас не так

Comment: @Crasher Дополнил

Comment: Ну, как пример, когда из базы получаете данные, первым шагом пишите их в ассоциативный массив вместо вывода, типа ```$coords[$row['id']] = array("lat"=>$row['latitude'], "lon"=>$row['longitude']);``` Вторым шагом возвращаемся к переменной $res, в которой у вас находится список id, полученных с сайта. Разбейте его на элементы массива ```$masIds = explode(",", $res);``` ну и тут уже пробегаемся по массиву и выводим данные ```foreach ($masIds as $id) {  echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$coords[$id]['lat'].','.$coords[$id]['lon'].'),'; }```. Код не тестил, может с ошибками, главное понять суть.

Comment: @Crasher Суть такая, от клиента приходит заказ, который записывается в таблицу orders там находится индификатор заказа, и id ресторана, например ресторан id1 моя цель, вывести на странице адрес ресторана из которого пришел заказ, а информация где находится  адрес ресторана, его широта и долгота на карте, находится в другой таблице restaurants в колонках latitude и longitude, в итоге получается таблица, ресторан id1 позиция на карте latitude и longitude. Вот сам смысл :) надеюсь понятно описал мою цель )

Comment: @Crasher В итоге, у меня на данный момент такой результат https://ads.pontogram.com/orderrest.php тепловая карта, две зеленые точки отображаются как два заказа из разных ресторанов, но в одном ресторане 1 заказ а в другом 10, а скрипт выводит только две записи по ID в место 15, одинаковые ID не выводит.